# gpt-3.5-turbo post request problem on node.js

Tags: node.js, json, http-post, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to get a response as a json
When I send a post request to api my outcome is just:
{
"success" : true
},
and my prompt object is this:
{
"prompt" : "anorexia nervosa restricting type"
}
and this my code:

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

app.post("/try", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { prompt } = req.body;
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "system",
          content: "you are a checklist provider",
        },
        {
          role: "user",
          content: `which symptom is should check about  ${prompt}`,
        },
      ],
      max_tokens: 1000,
      temperature: 0,
      top_p: 1.0,
      frequency_penalty: 0.0,
      presence_penalty: 0.0,
    });
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: response.data.choices[0].text,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: error.response
        ? error.response.data
        : "There is a problem on server bro :(",
    });
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log("server running"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix

```
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

app.post("/try", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { prompt } = req.body;
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "system",
          content: "you are a checklist provider",
        },
        {
          role: "user",
          content: `which symptom is should check about  ${prompt}`,
        },
      ],
      max_tokens: 1000,
      temperature: 0,
      top_p: 1.0,
      frequency_penalty: 0.0,
      presence_penalty: 0.0,
    });
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: response.data.choices[0].content, // its should be content here
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: error.response
        ? error.response.data
        : "There is a problem on server bro :(",
    });
  }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log("server running"));
```